# Generic order method by specific property

Tags: c#

I am quite new in generic programming and have a question:

I am trying to order a list by specific properties which should be defined as parameter.
Please look at the code for better understanding what I want:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SortEmployeesFor<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> list,
    property1,
    property2, 
    OrderOptions options)
{
    switch (options)
    {
        case OrderOptions.1:
            return list.OrderBy(x => property1).ThenBy(x => property2);

        case OrderOptions.2:
            return list.OrderBy(x => property2).ThenBy(x => x.property1);

        ...
    }

    return list;
}
```

Is there any option to perform this?

---

P.S. It's my first post, if I did something wrong, please understand and let me know.

Comment: what's the type of property1 and property2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look it up on MSDN you note that [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx), and `ThenBy` take a `Func<TSource, TKey>` as the key selector parameter.

So you could write some generic extension like this.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SortWithOptions<T, TKey1, TKey2>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, TKey1> selector1,
    Func<T, TKey2> selector2,
    OrderOptions options)
{
    switch (options)
    {
        case OrderOptions.One:
             return source.OrderBy(selector1).ThenBy(selector2);

        case OrderOptions.Two:
             return source.OrderBy(selector2).ThenBy(selector1);
    }
}
```

Then, if you want a non-generic implementation for employees you could write,

```
public static IEnumerable<Employee> SortEmployees(
    IEnumerable<Employee> unsorted,
    OrderOptions options)
{
    return unsorted.SortWithOptions(
        e => e.Cost,
        e => e.Ability,
        options);
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty good. I think this is exactly that I want. Thank you very much. It helps a lot

Answer (score 3):

Try passing in the sort properties as Funcs extracting a key from T.

So:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SortEmployeesFor<T>(
  IEnumerable<T> list,
  Func<T, TProp1> order1,
  Func<T, TProp2> order2, 
  OrderOptions options)
{
    switch (options)
    {
    case OrderOptions.1:
        return list.OrderBy(order1).ThenBy(order2);

    case OrderOptions.2:
        return list.OrderBy(order2).ThenBy(order1);

    ...
    }

    return list;
}
```

Usage:

```
SortEmployeesFor<MyType>(
  list, 
  new Func<MyType, typeOfProp1>(x => x.property1), 
  new Func<MyType, typeOfProp2>(x => x.property2), 
  OrderOptions.1);
```

Don't know if this is exactly syntactly correct, but it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SortEmployeesFor<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, IComparable> property1, Func<T, IComparable> property2, OrderOption option)
{
  switch (options)
  {
    case OrderOptions.1:
      return list.OrderBy(property1).ThenBy(property2);

    case OrderOptions.2:
      return list.OrderBy(property2).ThenBy(property1);
  }

  return list;
}
```

Then call it using something like this

`list = SortEmployeesFor(list, x => x.Id, y => y.Name, OrderOptions.1);`

Comment: This is similar to @Davio's answer however you do not need to explicitly specify the type of the property you want to order by

Comment: Maybe a bit more background: I have different "systems" with different view - objects of "Employees" and I want to offer a general sort- methode. This methode should get as overload the propertynames which are relevant for sorting. I thought about reflection, but I think/hope there would be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
list.OrderBy("SomeProperty DESC, SomeOtherProperty ASC");

list.OrderBy("SomeProperty");
list.OrderBy("SomeProperty DESC");
list.OrderBy("SomeProperty DESC, SomeOtherProperty");
list.OrderBy("SomeSubObject.SomeProperty ASC, SomeOtherProperty DESC");
```

See [Here](http://aonnull.blogspot.com/2010/08/dynamic-sql-like-linq-orderby-extension.html)

Comment: Using literals is bad practice

Comment: Thanks a lot I will have a look at this

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with linq.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SortEmployeesFor<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, OrderOptions options)
{
    switch (options)
    {
        case OrderOptions.1:
            list = from t in list
                     orderby t.property1, t.property2
                     select t;
        case OrderOptions.2:
            list = from t in list
                     orderby t.property2, t.property1
                     select t;        
        .
        .
        .
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Please tell me the difference between your answer and actual post??. Both are same.. xandi1987 used lamba expressions for sorting.. which is good. I think your post doesnot help.

Comment: Instead of using .OrderBy and ThenBy, it puts them together in a Linq query. I rather user IQueryable for this implementation, but want to follow original post aproach.